# UIWebView remember usernam and password ,an autofill it

Tags: ios, uiwebview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible for a UIWebView to save and autofill previously entered form values (e.g., username & password)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772341/is-it-possible-for-a-uiwebview-to-save-and-autofill-previously-entered-form-valu)

In my ios app, i create an UIWebView to log in a web. i want the webview can remember the username and the password, and they can be  autofilled to the web next time, so i don't need to type it again. i notice that it can be done in safari.but i don't know how to get it in UIWebView.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711246/ios-objective-c-uiwebview-autofill-and-execute) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772341/is-it-possible-for-a-uiwebview-to-save-and-autofill-previously-entered-form-valu)

Comment: in these two method.it seems that it use some form(like "nameOfOneInput",and "document.myForm.username.value") to get the username and password from javaScript.i wonder whether the form is usual to all the website.if not,how can it deal with different web? cus i use the method of the second link, but it doesn't work.

i am a chinese, so my english isn't very good.hope you can understand it.and i'm doing my best to improve my english.