# Authentication Challenge in UIWebview and Displaying URL in Objective C ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        isAuthenticated = false;
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://spo.mcd.com/sites/seeit_development3/brand/cognizant-test-brand-05242017"];`

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithUrl:url
                                                    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         if(error == nil) {
         } else {
           NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }
      }];
      [dataTask resume];
      return NO;
   }

   return YES;
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler{
    isAuthenticated = true;
        NSURLCredential *cred = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"UserName"
                                                           password:@"Password"
                                                        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, cred);
        NSLog(@"Finished Challenge");
}
```

After implementing the above, I get a response but the URL Never gets loaded in my WebView.

Basically in this URL `https://spo.mcd.com/sites/seeit_development3/brand/cognizant-test-brand-05242017` first a Login Screen Appears and then the Webpages gets loaded.

I getting a success but how do i load this URL in my Webview. Tries All types of ATS permissions. Nothing is working

Comment: Have you added `AppTransportSecurity`?

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
   <key>spo.mcd.com</key>
   <dict>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
    <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
    <true/>
   </dict>
  </dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
  <true/>
 </dict> NO CHANGE

Comment: Please take a look at: [Programmatically logging in to website with saved username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869418/programmatically-logging-in-to-website-with-saved-username-and-password)